# $f'(x)>g'(x)\,\forall x\in [a,\infty)\text{ and }f,\,g\underset{\infty}{\to}0\Rightarrow \lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)/g(x)=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis

Is this $f'(x)>g'(x)\,\forall x\in [a,\infty)\text{ and }f,\,g\underset{\infty}{\to}0\Rightarrow \lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)/g(x)=0$ correct? FALSE.

Can I say something about the limit's convergence, though?

**EDIT**: Initially I thought of two decreasing functions, but taking into account dfnu's answer below, I think the correct way to describe this is $|f'(x)|<|g'(x)|$, so that $f(x)$ is reaching $0$ faster than $g(x)$ plus add $f(x)\neq cg(x)$ to the assumptions.

**EDIT 2:**  What I want to say is, if there're two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ who are going to $0$ as $x\to\infty$, and such that after a certain $x\,(=a)$ we have $f'(x)>g'(x)$ then $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \underset{\infty}{\to} 0$ provided that $f(x)\neq cg(x)$ where $c\in\mathbb{R}$, elsewise the limit would equal $c$.

I realised some holes in this through answers and comments. I was initially thinking of two decreasing functions, i.e both positive.

However, since what I want to say is if $f$ goes to $0$ faster than $g$ then ..., the correct way to translate this in math is $|f'(x)|<|g'(x)|$ (provided that both $f$ and $g$ are going to $0$).

**EDIT 3:** through the different counter-examples given, it is clear that this is not true. however, given the premises, it seems that the limit always converges (maybe), and in the special case that $f\not\underset{\infty}{\sim}g$, it is zero (maybe). This is just an intuitive exercise, I just feel like this might work out.

**EDIT 4:** counter example for everything
$$f(x)=\left (\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sin x}{10}\right)e^{-x}\\g(x)=e^{-x}$$
Maybe everything holds if $(f/g)(x)$ isn't periodic.

**EDIT 5:** also false
$$f(x)=\left (\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sin \sqrt x}{10}\right)e^{-x}\\g(x)=e^{-x}$$

I think this might just lead to $f/g\not\underset{∞}{\to}±∞$ as pointed out to me in another forum, since $f$ is |growing| slower than $g$.

Comment: Take $f(x)=x^{-3}$ and $g(x)=x^{-2}$, after $1.5$ we have $f'(x)>g'(x)$ and the limit of  $f/g$ at $\infty$ is $0<1$.

Comment: correct. My comment was mistakenly based on positive derivatives.

Comment: In your edit, do you mean $|f'(x)|>|g'(x)|$? Also: should'nt you also explicitly state $g(x) \neq 0$, for otherwise the limit $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ might not exist?

Comment: @dnfu no, I meant it as it is. since they are both going to 0, the absolute of the rate of change of $f$ being less than that of $g$ means that $f$ is going to $0$ faster.

Comment: Sorry, I got confused.

Comment: What about taking $$g(x) = \frac1{1+x^2}+e^{-x}$$ and $$f(x) = \frac12 \cdot \frac1{1+x^2}+e^{-x}?$$

Comment: @dfnu through the different examples given, I became aware that this is probably better to express convergence. i.e given the premises, the limit converges (maybe). however, if $f$ and $g$ aren't equivalent at infinity, then the limit is zero.

Comment: I think if you slightly modify your last counterexample with $$f(x) = \left(\frac12 + \frac{\sin\sqrt x}{10}\right)e^{-x}$$you'll get another one where $f/g$ isn't periodic.

Comment: @dfnu spot on. I think this might just lead to $f/g \not\underset{\infty}{\to}\pm\infty$ as pointed out to me in another forum, since $f$ is |growing| slower than $g$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101839/discussion-between-dfnu-and-luyw).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not true, consider $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$ and $g(x)=\frac{2}{x^2}$. Such $a$ exists, that for every $x>a$ $f'(x)>g'(x)$. Both converge to 0, but:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\frac{1}{x^2}}{\frac{2}{x^2}} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: $g'>f'$ here for $x>1.5$

Comment: @Luyw yes, you're right, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=\frac12g(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$.  We have $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to \infty}g(x)=0$.

Although for $x\ge 0$, $f'>g'$, $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac12\ne0$.

Comment: Can I say that the limit would always converge?

Comment: And I think that if $f\neq cg$ then this might hold?

Answer (score 1):

You have no restrictions on the sign of $f$ and $g$? Then I guess you can't say much about convergence, either. Take, in $(0,+\infty)$, $$f(x) = -\frac1x$$ and $$g(x)= e^{-x}.$$ They both converge to $0$ when $x\to+\infty$, and $g'(x)=-e^{-x}<0<\frac1{x^2}=f'(x)$, and
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=-\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{e^x}{x}=-\infty.$$

Comment: I pictured them both to be decreasing, so I guess the best way to describe it is $|f'(x)|<|g'(x)|$